# GCD of $X^4+5X^3+3X^2+X$ and $X^2+1$ ( Euclidean Algorithm + Finding the inverse of the polynomial)

Tags: polynomials, gcd-and-lcm, euclidean-algorithm

It is obvious the GCD of those two is 1.

The thing that makes me post this question is that why when using Euclidean Algorithm the GCD seems to be $ \frac{5}{4}$ ?

I want furthermore to find the inverse of the polynomial and i know i can do that when the GCD = 1 by using Extended Euclidean Algorithm. Yet as i've said i have 5/4.

Comment: $5/4$ is a unit (invertible) in the ring of polynomials with inverse $4/5$. It is like if you find that $-1$ is the gcd between two (rational) integers. People don't count an invertible factor.

Comment: Divide your whole equation by $5/4$ and you get an equation with 1.

Comment: OH RIGHT!! Thank you very much !!

Comment: That's the reason why people don't count units as interesting factors, you can divide them out as you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what? The conclusion (assuming that the computations are correct) is that $\frac54$ is *a* GCD of your polynomials. This is the same thing as saying that they are relatively prime.

Comment: The thing is that furthermore i want to find the inverse of the polynomial. If from Euclid i didn't get 1 i don't know how am i supposed to continue\

Comment: @Eduard6421 What's the problem? Start with $\frac54$ and express it as $\alpha(x)p(x)+\beta(x)q(x)$, where $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ are your polynomials. Then $1=\frac45\alpha(x)p(x)+\frac45\beta(x)q(x)$.

Comment: I don't know how did i let that slip, that s completely obvious.. 
Thank you a lot!